# Pagination Redirect with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, pagination

I want to redirect the `/page/2` style pagination pages to `?page=2` and to the others in this format.

So any urls like these:

```
https://www.example.com/dogs/page/2
https://www.example.com/horses/videos/page/3
https://www.example.com/cats/photos/page/4
```

will be redirected to:

```
https://www.example.com/dogs?page=2
https://www.example.com/horses/videos?page=3
https://www.example.com/cats/photos?page=4
```

Comment: please show your attempt

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(/.*)/page/(.*)$ (/.*)?page=*$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: @macc, since you mentioned `$` after `(.*)` so portion after that on your regex is not getting read/executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing these URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1?%2=%3 [L]
```

Comment: @macc, Hello macc, could you please do let me know if this solution has helped you here?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)/page/(\d+)/?$ $1?page=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```